# Reduce array of objects in es6 - using unique set of params

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array of objects. In each object there is an **id** property and an array property called **rates**. I would to reduce this object such that there are no duplicate object records. A duplicate record is defined as BOTH unique id and rates array. So for this example, id 345 appears twice and has same rates array - and is therefore a duplicate. id 123 appears twice, but rates array is different - so therefore is not a duplicate.

```
const sampleArray = [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
    },
    {
      "id": "345",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
    },
    {
      "id": "123",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}, {"id": "456", "totalPrice": 500}]
    },
    {
      "id": "345",
      rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
    }
]
```

Expected Output

```
const sampleArray = [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
    },
    {
      "id": "345",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
    },
    {
      "id": "123",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}, {"id": "456", "totalPrice": 500}]
    }
]
```

Comment: Your code blocks have syntax errors.

Comment: Not anymore, they don't 

Answer (score 0):

Use Lodash and its [`isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual):

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

function makeUnique( xs ) {
  const ys = [];

  for ( const x of xs ) {
    let equal = false;

    for ( const y of ys ) {
      equal = _.isEqual(x,y);
      if (equal) break;
    }

    if (!equal) {
      ys.push(x);
    }

  }

  return ys;
}

const sampleArray = [
  {
    id: "123",
    rates: [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
  },
  {
    id: "345",
    rates: [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
  },
  {
    id: "123",
    rates: [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}, {"id": "456", "totalPrice": 500}]
  },
  {
    id: "345",
    rates: [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
  },
];

const unique = makeUnique(sampleArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(unique, undefined, 2));
```

This writes

```js
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "rates": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "totalPrice": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "345",
    "rates": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "totalPrice": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "rates": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "totalPrice": 100
      },
      {
        "id": "456",
        "totalPrice": 500
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To the console.

Comment: Hmm... I seem to be getting an empty array with this solution. Do you have an alternative or one without having to use lodash? Appreciate it!

Comment: @Michael — fixed it for ya! (I'm a little slow today).

Comment: No worries! for some reason i'm not getting expected behavior still. it's returning all objects in new array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to build the desired output, additionally, you have to use the functions `Array.prototype.every` and `Array.prototype.some` to validate the uniqueness between two rate arrays.

```js
const sampleArray = [    {      "id": "123",      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]    },    {      "id": "345",      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]    },    {      "id": "123",      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}, {"id": "456", "totalPrice": 500}]    },    {"id": "345","rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]}],
      result = Object.values(sampleArray.reduce((a, c) => {
        let key = `${c.id}_${c.rates.length}`;
        if (a[key] && a[key].rates.every((rate) => { 
            let rateKeys = Object.keys(rate);
            return c.rates.some((innerRate) => rateKeys.every(key => rate[key] === innerRate[key]));
          })) {
          // The current object "c" is present in the accumulator, because of the following:
          //   1. The key (`${c.id}_${c.rates.length}`) already exists within the accumulator.
          //   2. All the key-values of object "c" are present in the current object within the accumulator
          return a;
        } else {
          // The current object "c" is not present in the accumulator
          return Object.assign(a, {[key]: {...c}});
        }
      }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: sorry, but can we make this more dynamic? there will actually end up being more data in these objects. but id and rates are the most important to compare... would really like to compare length of rate array to validate uniqueness

Comment: Thanks! Can you briefly explain what is happening in each if / else block? And also what's the purpose of Object.create(null)? Can this be {} instead? Appreciate it :)

Comment: @Michael done, this `Object.create(null)` creates an object that doesn't inherit from anything, and yes, you can use `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const sampleArray = [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
    },
    {
      "id": "345",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
    },
    {
      "id": "123",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}, {"id": "456", "totalPrice": 500}]
    },
    {
      "id": "345",
      "rates": [{"id": "123", "totalPrice": 100}]
    }
]

const res = sampleArray.reduce((acc, { id, rates }) => {
  if(!(acc.some(item => item.id === id) 
    && (acc.find(item => item.id === id)?.rates.every(r => rates.find(rr => rr.id === r.id && rr.totalPrice === r.totalPrice)))
    && rates?.length === acc.find(item => item.id === id)?.rates.length)) {
      acc.push({
        id, 
        rates
      })  
  }

  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(res);
```